# Destroy a session in Load Impact

Tags: azure, lua

I have created a user scenario in Load Impact to simulate a couple of hundred users in our web store.

The problem is that I can't seem to simulate the users in our Azure Queue.
The queue is only increasing with +1 users and not the hundreds of users as I want :)

I have created a random correlation id, but it seems like the session is still there.

Is there a way to destroy the session so when the script is looping a new session is created?

I found a LUA reference that says `destroy:session` but it wont work for me.

```
function rnd()
  return math.random(0000, 9999)
end

   {"POST", "http://STORE.////", 
      headers={["Content-Type"]="application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, 
      data="{\"ChoosenPhoneModelId\":0,\"PricePlanId\":\"phone\",\"CorrelationId\":\"e97bdaf6-ed61-4fb3-".. rnd().."-d3bb09789feb\",\"ChoosenPhoneColor\":{\"Color\":1,\"Code\":\"#d0d0d4\",\"Name\":\"Silver\",\"DeliveryTime\":\"1-2 veckor\",\"$$hashKey\":\"005\"},\"ChoosenAmortization\":{\"AmortizationLength\":24,\"Price\":312,\"$$hashKey\":\"00H\"},\"ChoosenPriceplan\":{\"IsPostpaid\":true,\"IsStudent\":false,\"IsSenior\":false,\"Title\":\"Fast \",\"Description\":\"Hello.\",\"MonthlyAmount\":149,\"AvailiableDataPackages\":null,\"SubscriptionBinding\":1,\"$$hashKey\":\"00M\"},\"ChoosenDataPackage\":{\"Description\":\"20 

GB\",\"PricePerMountInKr\":149,\"DataAmountInGb\":20,\"$$hashKey\":\"00U\"}}", 
          auto_decompress=true}
})
```

Any tips on how to.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The correlation id isn't a random number. It's set by your server in a cookie. Get and use like this:

```
local response = http.request_batch({
    {"GET", "http://store.///step1", auto_decompress=true},
})

-- extract correlation Id
local strCorrelationId = response[1].cookies['corrIdCookie']


    {"POST", "http://STORE.////", 
      headers={["Content-Type"]="application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, 
      data="{\"ChoosenPhoneModelId\":0,\"PricePlanId\":\"phone\",\"CorrelationId\":\"".. strCorrelationId .. "",\"ChoosenPhoneColor\":{\"Color\":1,\"Code\":\"#d0d0d4\",\"Name\":\"Silver\",\"DeliveryTime\":\"1-2 veckor\",\"$$hashKey\":\"005\"},\"ChoosenAmortization\":{\"AmortizationLength\":24,\"Price\":312,\"$$hashKey\":\"00H\"},\"ChoosenPriceplan\":{\"IsPostpaid\":true,\"IsStudent\":false,\"IsSenior\":false,\"Title\":\"Fast \",\"Description\":\"Hello.\",\"MonthlyAmount\":149,\"AvailiableDataPackages\":null,\"SubscriptionBinding\":1,\"$$hashKey\":\"00M\"},\"ChoosenDataPackage\":{\"Description\":\"20 

GB\",\"PricePerMountInKr\":149,\"DataAmountInGb\":20,\"$$hashKey\":\"00U\"}}", 
          auto_decompress=true}
})
```

That is what makes your user unique. If you set CorrelationId to just any random number your server will simply not accept the session in your queue.

Once it's unique and correct your server will accept the POST properly.